# Change Google Doc when print button clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, listener

Is it possible to put a listener on a Google Document for when the print button is pressed? What I would like to do specifically is change the date on the page to be the current date when the print button is clicked so that the current date is printed out. I want to do this so that the actual document isn't changed constantly on open and I can leave a keyword that will be replaced on print only (for example: [[DATE]]).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Good question. I don't believe there is any communication between apps scripts and the printer. This would be an excellent feature, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Add a menu item 'prepare for printing'.
Might also be possible to launch a google cloud print job from the menu (doubt it though, you would need to code that manually as gas doesnt support it either)